# WPF C# - Conditional ItemSorce in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have the next code:

**C#**

```
public class CalculatedPointModel
{
        public string PointId { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CalculatedBeamModel> CalculatedBeamsByPoint { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<CalculatedPlanModel> CalculatedPlanByPoint { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Data
{
        public ObservableCollection<CalculatedPointModel> CalculatedPoints { get; private set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
        <Expander Grid.Row="0" Header="Results"  Margin ="0,0,0,5">
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Margin="25,10,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding CalculatedPoints}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                       
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Border Grid.Row="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PointId}"/>
                            </Border>
                            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CalculatedBeamsByPoint OR CalculatedPlanByPoint}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                         
                                       DataGridTextColumns depends on whether binding is CalculatedBeamsByPoint or CalculatedBeamsByPoint 
                                    
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>                            
                           // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Expander>
```

Depending on whether the bending is CalculatedBeamsByPoint or CalculatedPlanByPoint (its selection depends on the value of a class property) the headers and data of one or the other ObservableCollection will be shown. How can I do it? I have tried it with triggers and converters but it doesn't work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: _I have tried it with triggers and converters but it doesn't work for me._ I am not able to find that in your code, so it's hard to tell what your problem is.

Comment: Create two DataTemplates for the ItemsControl and select the appropriate one by means of its ItemTemplateSelector.

Comment: @Rubi: How do you currently set the `ItemsSource`?

Comment: Thanks Clemens. That is exactly what I needed.